# Compare LINA and Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I was wondering how [LINA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINA_%28software%29) and [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) are different, in terms of their type, their purpose, ...? As WIkipedia says, both are compatible layers for Linux on Windows.

Which one is better or when to use which?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I've been using cygwin for years. Didn't even know about Lina.

Answer (score 3):

The most significant difference appears to be that LINA is dead, since its last release happened almost two years ago and its domain name is up for grabs.